# Javascript Canvas Constructing Path with Different Colors

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, canvas

I have two global variables `currentx` and `currenty` and two functions :

```
function MoveUp()   
{
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
ctx.moveTo(currentx,currenty);
ctx.lineTo(currentx+20,currenty-20);
ctx.stroke();

currentx=currentx+20;
currenty=currenty-20;

}

function MoveDown()   
{
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle="green";
ctx.moveTo(currentx,currenty);
ctx.lineTo(currentx+20,currenty-20);
ctx.stroke();

currentx=currentx-20;
currenty=currenty-20;

}
```

Every time I call function `MoveUp()` I want to draw a blue line and every time I call `MoveDown()` I want to write green line. I can not use `beginPath()`  because each time with ups and downs, I continue drawing my path the whole time. Is it possible to do it without using `beginPath()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to use *beginPath*, but you can also use *closePath* to end a certain "mini-path"-section of a whole path (second example). In this way each paths do not intervene with each other's color.

---

**First example** (draws whole path in a certain color):

You could remember the path you have moved so far.

First you could start at x:0, y:0 and by pressing either up and down each line is stored into a variable called *path*.

This *path* is always painted either in blue or in green when up or down is pressed, accordining to your question.

Your both function *MoveUp* and *MoveDown* handle your current position, the direction that determines your color, the path and call finally *handleDirection* to show your path accordingly to those values.

How to use this example:

1. Click on the "Run code snippet"-Button
2. Click into the field that is dragged down
3. Press either arrow-up or down to draw

Hope this example helps.

```js
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var direction = null;
  var currentx=0, currenty=0;
  var startPoint = {
    x:currentx,
    y:currenty
  };
  var path = [];

  function addLineToPath(line){
    path.push({
      x:line.x,
      y:line.y
    });
  }

  function redrawPath(color){
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    path.forEach(function(line){
      context.lineTo(line.x, line.y);
    });
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = color;
    context.stroke();
  }

  function handleDirection(){
    switch(direction){
      case 'UP':
        redrawPath('blue');
        break;
      case 'DOWN':
        redrawPath('green');
        break;
    };
  }

  function MoveUp()
  {
    currentx = currentx + 20; // move right: x always becomes bigger
    currenty = currenty - 20; // move up: y always becomes smaller
    addLineToPath({x:currentx,y:currenty}); // update your path to your current position 
    direction = 'UP'; // this determines the path-color
    handleDirection();
  }

  function MoveDown()
  {
    currentx = currentx + 20; // move right: x always becomes bigger
    currenty = currenty + 20; // move down: y always becomes bigger
    addLineToPath({x:currentx,y:currenty}); // update your path to your current position 
    direction = 'DOWN'; // this determines the path-color
    handleDirection();
  }

  var UP = 38;
  var DOWN = 40;
  
  var getKey = function(e) {
    if(window.event) { return e.keyCode; }  // IE
    else if(e.which) { return e.which; }    // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
  };

  document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){

    var keynum = getKey(e);

    if(keynum === UP) {
      MoveUp();
    }

    if(keynum === DOWN) {
      MoveDown();
    }

  }, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

---

**Second example** (draws paths each in a certain color with ugly line breaks):

Another example to change line-color alternately. In *redrawPath* each line has got a color as well. Furthermore when drawing a "mini-path", it is started at the end of the former "mini-path"-line:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var currentx = 0, currenty = 0;
var path = [];

// to check for certain arrows
var UP = 38;
var DOWN = 40;

function addLineToPath(line) {
  path.push({
    x: line.x,
    y: line.y,
    color: line.color
  });
}

function redrawPath() {
  
  canvas.width = canvas.width;
  
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  var lastLine = {x:0,y:0};
  path.forEach(function (line) {
    // draws a mini-path line by line
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(lastLine.x, lastLine.y);
    context.lineTo(line.x, line.y);
    context.strokeStyle = line.color;
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
    lastLine = line;
  });
  
}

function MoveUp()
{
  currentx = currentx + 20; // move right: x always becomes bigger
  currenty = currenty - 20; // move up: y always becomes smaller
  addLineToPath({
    x: currentx,
    y: currenty,
    color: 'blue'
  }); // update your path to your current position
  redrawPath();
}

function MoveDown()
{
  currentx = currentx + 20; // move right: x always becomes bigger
  currenty = currenty + 20; // move down: y always becomes bigger
  addLineToPath({
    x: currentx,
    y: currenty,
    color: 'green'
  }); // update your path to your current position
  redrawPath();
}

var getKey = function (e) {
  if (window.event) {
    return e.keyCode;
  } // IE
   else if (e.which) {
    return e.which;
  } // Netscape/Firefox/Opera

};

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  var keynum = getKey(e);
  if (keynum === UP) {
    MoveUp();
  }
  if (keynum === DOWN) {
    MoveDown();
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

---

**Third example** (draws smoothed paths each in a certain color):

In this example *quadraticCurveTo* is used to smooth out those ugly line breaks occurring when there is a change in direction:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var currentx = 0, currenty = 0;
var path = [];

// to check for certain arrows
var UP = 38;
var DOWN = 40;

function addLineToPath(line) {
  path.push({
    x: line.x,
    y: line.y,
    color: line.color
  });
}

function redrawPath() {
  canvas.width = canvas.width;
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var lastLine = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };
  path.forEach(function (line) {
    // draws a mini-path line by line
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(lastLine.x, lastLine.y);

    // a pixel should be enough to have a smoothing effect
    var smoothPixelInX = 1;
    var smoothPixelInY = line.color === 'blue' ? smoothPixelInX : - smoothPixelInX;

    // if there is a change in color there is a line break
    var colorChange = lastLine.color !== line.color;
    if (colorChange) {
      // smooths out ugly line breaks
      context.quadraticCurveTo(lastLine.x, lastLine.y + smoothPixelInY, line.x + smoothPixelInX, line.y - smoothPixelInY);
    }
    else {
      // smooths out ugly line interruptions
      context.lineTo(line.x+smoothPixelInX, line.y-smoothPixelInY);
    }
    context.strokeStyle = line.color;
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
    lastLine = line;
  });
}

function MoveUp()
{
  currentx = currentx + 20; // move right: x always becomes bigger
  currenty = currenty - 20; // move up: y always becomes smaller
  addLineToPath({
    x: currentx,
    y: currenty,
    color: 'blue'
  }); // update your path to your current position
  redrawPath();
}

function MoveDown()
{
  currentx = currentx + 20; // move right: x always becomes bigger
  currenty = currenty + 20; // move down: y always becomes bigger
  addLineToPath({
    x: currentx,
    y: currenty,
    color: 'green'
  }); // update your path to your current position
  redrawPath();
}

var getKey = function (e) {
  if (window.event) {
    return e.keyCode;
  } // IE
   else if (e.which) {
    return e.which;
  } // Netscape/Firefox/Opera

};

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  var keynum = getKey(e);
  if (keynum === UP) {
    MoveUp();
  }
  if (keynum === DOWN) {
    MoveDown();
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but what I meant was writing the ups in the path with blue and writing the downs with green so that the path would be for example green,green,blue,green,blue ect...

Comment: I just corrected my answer take onather look on my second example, please.

Comment: for information only: The second example has been updated. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you very much again, I checked it and it works perfectly.Maybe irrelevant but I have one more very quick question, I need to draw a curve as well. I am using quadraticCurveTo() function.It works fine however my curve needs to be above the x=0 axis.This function draws it under the x=0 axis. Do you happen to know how can I invert this curve ? Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome! Sorry, but you have to post another question again to show what you have done. I'm sure there is  a suitable answer.

Comment: Hope this third example is what you've been looking for. I could not come up with another idea to use quadraticCurveTo.